# getResourceAsStream() doesn't read nothing

Tags: java, netbeans, filepath

I'm joking with a java trying to program a game, I'm not going to define useless details, the program works, but it works only if I get it from the point where I developed it (Netbeans), but if I try to get it started Jar nothing, I read on the internet that to access files, such as images or txt files, you have to use the Class.class.getResourceAsStream (path), but the latter does not work from starting it from the jar, in fact or me From a NullPointerException or goes smooth, but does not load anything.

Disappeared I would explain the structure of my project and show you my code:

List build

```
 -build
    - classes
        - mario
           -all the package and the file example: crediti/ringraziamenti.txt
```

List dist

```
    -dist
         -jarFile
              -mario
                    -all the package and the file example: crediti/ringraziamenti.txt
              -meta inf...
```

List java

```
    -src
        -mario
              - all the package and the file example: crediti/ringraziamenti.txt
```

my code is:

```
        InputStream io =(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mario/crediti/ringraziamenti.txt"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(io));

        String temp = "";
        while((temp = br.readLine())== null){
            System.out.println(""+temp);
        }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: `while((temp = br.readLine())== null){` - the `==` is very suspicious.

Comment: Cabbage that figure ... Tiredness must have given me the head to commit such a mistake ... And think that it was two hours I did not understand where the problem was, what a shame ... Thanks anyway to have pointed out to me my mistake.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fix your code as follows:

1. Put a slash in front of the path in the `getResourceAsStream` call, otherwise it will start searching from the package of the current class.
2. In the while loop, compare `!= null` rather than `== null` - you want the loop to continue running *as long as there lines of text*, not as long as there are *no lines* of text.

```
InputStream io =(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/mario/crediti/ringraziamenti.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(io));

String temp;
while((temp = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(""+temp);
}
```

Comment: “otherwise it will start searching from the package of the current class” is not correct.  Class.getResourceAsStream works that way;  Class**Loader**.getResourceAsStream does not.  An initial slash is never valid for the latter method.

Answer (score -1):

Specify a resource folder, put your files there. Assuming you have structure:

> -src
>           -mario
>                 - all the package and the file example: 
>   crediti/ringraziamenti.txt

add the `resource` folder on the same level as your packages, move your files there and try:

```
InputStream io =(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/crediti/ringraziamenti.txt"));
```